# Build array of parent paths back

Tags: javascript

I need to build an array of paths based on the current directory back to a predefined top level directory.

In Javascript have two variables 'topLevelDirectory' and 'currentDirectory'

I need an array of all paths in between.

example :

```
 topLevelDirectory = "/sectionA/sectionB"
    currentDirectory = "/sectionA/sectionB/sectionC/sectionD/sectionE
```

"

I need an array 'allPaths' that would have the values:

```
allPaths[0] = '/sectionA/sectionB/'
   allPaths[1] = '/sectionA/sectionB/sectionC/'
   allPaths[2] = '/sectionA/sectionB/sectionC/sectionD/'
   allPaths[3] = '/sectionA/sectionB/sectionC/sectionD/sectionE/'
```

I am using Jquery.

I know I can split currentDirectory but then I am not getting the value I need,
  'sectionC' instead of '/sectionA/sectionB/sectionC/'

I am not expecting the full code to the answer, just some help in what functions or procedures I should be trying to tie together.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't very elegant or terribly robust, but it seems to work for your example...

```
function segmentPath(topLevelDir, currentDir) {

    function normalizePath(str) {
        return str.replace(/(^\/+|\/+$)/g, ''); // strip leading/trailing slashes
    }

    topLevelDir = normalizePath(topLevelDir);
    currentDir = normalizePath(currentDir);

    var relativePath = normalizePath(currentDir.slice(topLevelDir.length));
    relativePath = relativePath.split('/');

    var segments = ["/" + topLevelDir];

    for (var i = 0, l = relativePath.length; i < l; i++) {
        segments.push(segments[i] + "/" + relativePath[i]);
    }

    return segments;
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QrCBn/

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly, I am going to try all three answers then accept one.

Answer (score 2):

decided against regular expressions because they might be confusing to a beginner. it's worth pointing out that you do not need jQuery to solve this problem, plain ol' javascript will do. i've commented the code in the hope that you will understand what's going on. remove the `console.log` at the end when you are happy it works

```
function getAllPaths (topLevelDirectory, currentDirectory) {        

    //split into individual directories
    var topLevelSegments = topLevelDirectory.split("/");
    var currentSegments = currentDirectory.split("/");


    //initialise allPaths array with just the top level directory
    var permutation = topLevelDirectory + "/";
    var allPaths = [permutation];


    //start appending directories that sit below topLevelDirectory 
    for(i = topLevelSegments.length; i < currentSegments.length; i++) {    
        permutation = permutation + currentSegments[i] + "/";
        allPaths.push(permutation); 
    }
    return allPaths;
}

var topLevelDir = "/sectionA/sectionB",
        currentDir = "/sectionA/sectionB/sectionC/sectionD/sectionE";

var allPaths = getAllPaths(topLevelDir, currentDir);
console.log(allPaths);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PpEH4/

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly, I am going to try all three answers then accept one.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getAllPaths(d0, d1) {
  d0 = (""+d0).replace(/\/$/, '');
  d1 = (""+d1).replace(/\/$/, '');
  var paths=[d0], ps=d1.slice(d0.length+1).split('/'), i;
  for (i=1; i<=ps.length; i++) {
    paths.push(d0 + '/' + ps.slice(0, i).join('/'));
  }
  return (d1.indexOf(d0) < 0 && /^\//.test(d0)) ? [] : paths;
}

var paths = getAllPaths(topLevelDir, currentDir);
paths; // ["/sectionA/sectionB", "/sectionA/sectionB/sectionC", "/sectionA/sectionB/sectionC/sectionD", "/sectionA/sectionB/sectionC/sectionD/sectionE"]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly, I am going to try all three answers then accept one.